# Select the first set of divs on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a html structure like:

```
<h3>Attributes (<a class="on_test" href="#">show/hide all</a>)</h3>
<div class="reference_tborder">
<ul class="reference_table">
    <li>
      <p class="attribute_title"><a href="#" onClick="$(this).parent().nextAll('.attribute_description:first').slideToggle('slow'); return false;">style</a></p>
      <div class="attribute_description" style="display:none;">test1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="attribute_title"><a href="#" onClick="$(this).parent().nextAll('.attribute_description:first').slideToggle('slow'); return false;">type</a></p>
      <div class="attribute_description" style="display:none;">test1</div>
    </li>
</ul></div>

<h3>Attributes (<a class="on_test" href="#">show/hide all</a>)</h3>
<div class="reference_tborder">
<ul class="reference_table">
    <li>
      <p class="attribute_title"><a href="#" onClick="$(this).parent().nextAll('.attribute_description:first').slideToggle('slow'); return false;">style</a></p>
      <div class="attribute_description" style="display:none;">test2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="attribute_title"><a href="#" onClick="$(this).parent().nextAll('.attribute_description:first').slideToggle('slow'); return false;">type</a></p>
      <div class="attribute_description" style="display:none;">test2</div>
    </li>
</ul></div>
```

and more like these

and javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.on_test').click(function(event) {
        if ($('.attribute_description:first').css("display") == 'block') {
            $("div.attribute_description").css("display", "none");
        }
        else {
            $("div.attribute_description").css("display", "block");
        }
        return false;
    });
});​
</script>
```

Right now when I click "show/hide all", the action gets applied to all the divs. I just want to select the first ones under the "show/hide all" I click. Any help to approach solving this problem will be appreciated

Here's a JSFiddle so you can see the problem http://jsfiddle.net/5mLys/

Comment: Where are the closing tags for your `reference_tborder` divs?

Comment: oops...missed it....chk the update

Comment: (not that this will fix it) But I would use `.is(":visible")` for the `if` statement, and just use `.hide()` and `.show()` for the hiding and showing.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5mLys/2/ is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan I think that's close, but the OP would like both items to toggle when you click, your example is toggling one of them only.

Comment: @JuanMendes, that's why i am asking him coz he did not mentioned it clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to do:

```
$('a.on_test').on('click', function (e) {
    var _nextSection  = $(this).closest('h3').next().find('.reference_table'),
        _descriptions = _nextSection.find('.attribute_description');

    if (_descriptions.first().is(':visible')) {
        _descriptions.hide();
    }
    else {
        _descriptions.show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

You want to start by grabbing the nearest section, that way you won't be toggling multiple sections.

Side note: You should probably reconsider your general HTML structure, looks like you have div-itis here.

Comment: @Vinit I think deciding to show/hide all based on the visibility of the first one is a bad user experience. Consider using a checkbox, so that when't it's checked, the link shows all, when it's unchecked, it hides all

Answer (score 1):

You're searching the entire page all the time, contain your search to the `.reference_tborder` following the link. Also, you should use `$.toggle`, instead of doing it on your own.

http://sfiddle.net/5mLys/3/

```
$('a.on_test').click(function(event) {
    $('.attribute_description', $(this).parent().next()).toggle();
    return false;
});
```

**UPDATE**

Since you want more of a show/hide button, I think a better experience is to have a checkbox that indicates what state you're going to set it to instead of relying on the first item. The following should do it

**HTML**

```
<h3>Attributes (<label><input type='checkbox' class="show-hide"> show/hide all</label> )</h3>
```

**JS**

```
$('input.show-hide').change(function() {
    var toShowHide =  $('.attribute_description', $(this).closest('h3').next());
    if (this.checked) {
        toShowHide.show(); 
    } else {
        toShowHide.hide();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5mLys/6/

[image: Sample]

Comment: @Vinit what is the expected behavior if they are not in the same state?

Comment: we can check the first one...if hidden then make all hidden. If shown then make all shown

Comment: @Vinit That is a bad user experience in my opinion. Try the following which uses a checkbox to determine what the next state should be http://jsfiddle.net/5mLys/6/